# Can I run a docker container inside of a docker container?

Tags: docker, deployment

E.g., my local setup is to run a server (listens to `:1111`) and a docker container (with `-p 5555:5555`). The purpose is that a server can send the requests to docker container as well (to `:5555`).

I think that *the typical way* to deploy servers is to wrap it in a docker image and run the docker image in the cloud. How can I do the same thing but run my custom docker container inside of a server automatically (e.g., add `docker run` command to a `Dockerfile`)?

Comment: From your description it seems like you do NOT need to run docker in docker (which should be avoided anyway, or at least be in a "sibling" configuration). You just need to run two containers that have access to each other. Have you tried docker-compose?

Comment: No, I haven't, but you comment makes me think that it totally makes sense to look into that direction.

Comment: Yes, try docker-compose then - it will help you understand better how to create containers that talk to each other easily. Remember that docker-compose is just a convenience wrapper around the docker command itself, so everything it does can be done with pure docker.